# Problems with functions calling other functions in a Node.js library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.

I moved a bunch of front in functions from my library into a new Node.js library.

I know you have to put it in  module.exports = {

and all of the functions have to be of this format:
    tempToFahrenheit: function(tempInC){

I'm calling the functions from my other script fine but I'm having a problem with the functions calling each other:

```
tempToFahrenheit: function(tempInC){
    tempInF = (tempInC*1.8)+32;
    return tempInF;
},

getTextWeatherUsingStationUsingRequest: function(theStation){

    const http = require("http");
    const https = require("https");

    // theURL = 'https://api.weather.gov/stations/' + theStation + '/observations/current';
    thePath = '/stations/' + theStation + '/observations/current';


    function requestTheData(){

        var returnedJSON;

        var options = {
          protocol: "https:",
          hostname: "api.weather.gov",
          path: thePath,
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            'Accept'       : 'application/json',  
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'User-Agent'   : 'MY-TEST-UA'
          }

        };
        var req= https.request(options);

        var theData = '';

        req.on("response", function(res){
            console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
            console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
              console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
              theData += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log('No more data in response.');                   

                returnedJSON = JSON.parse(theData);
                console.log(returnedJSON.id);

                // Why can't ot find temptoFahrenheit
                theTemp = Math.round( tempToFahrenheit(returnedJSON.properties.temperature.value) )

                windSpeed = Math.round(returnedJSON.properties.windSpeed.value);
                pressure = returnedJSON.properties.barometricPressure.value;
```

Just above this text you'll see a line trying to call tempToFahrenheit() inside function getTextWeatherUsingStationUsingRequest(). How do I accomplish this? The strange way you have to set up the functions for Node.js (a hash right?) the functions don't seem to have access to each other.

Another more general question. Node.js benefits are supposed to be that you are using Javascript on front and back end and that you can REUSE code, as in libraries. But as we can see here I'm having to make pretty major (and error prone) changes to the code in order for it to work with Node. Also, I'm having to keep two copies of the library, one front end and the other Node. Isn't there a better way to do libraries in Node?

Comment: are you declaring these functions in an object ? `{ tempToFahrenheit: ..., otherfunction : ..}` ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey yes   module.exports = { tempToFahrenheit: ..., otherfunction : ..}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Node library, all of the functions are members of a common object (`modules.exports`). Therefore, when you want to call one function from another, you must specify that you're calling `this.someFunction`, not just `someFunction` (the latter will look for a globally-accessible `someFunction`, which doesn't exist).

Complicating things a little further, though, if you were to try that in your case, `this` would refer to the incorrect context, since that call is nested inside a couple asynchronous callbacks (`req.on` and `res.on`). You'd therefore have the same problem.

To get resolve this, try adding `var self=this;` at the beginning of your `getTextWeatherUsingStationUsingRequest` function, and then change your `tempToFahrenheit` function call to `self.tempToFahrenheit`.

(The variable `self` will propagate correctly through the callbacks through a feature called [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). `this` doesn't do that because it's a reserved keyword which always refers to the current context.)